# Native method for checking occurence of item in a pandas.core.series.Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm writing a little function for selecting rows from a .xlsx file by reading it in as a pandas dataframe and looping through it with the .iterrows() method. Each row is yielded as a `pandas.core.series.Series` type. Now I want to do a series of boolean checks to see if certain elements (a matching string, a certain numerical value etc.) is in that `pd.Series`. How I'd usually do that in plain builtin syntax is to simply ask: `if item in container: do X`, but I found that this only works on `list` types, which I confimed by converting the row to a python list using the list() function. So I wanted to know, if there is a native pandas method/function for that, or if I should just use my current fix (my current fix finds the length of two set() objects, which I figured would be a lot faster than converting to lists).

This is important to me, since I like to know how to optimize for preformance ahead of time. I run into all sorts of problems as of late due to poor preformance, even though I run a pretty strong system (CPU: Ryzen 7 3700X). One day I might have to loop through some gigantic .csv doing the same operations and unless I settle for using a JIT compiler (which I don't know the general applicability of), this might take ages. So: Is there a native pandas method to do this and will it preform better than my current solution?

Here's an excerpt from the .xlsx (perhaps more than necessary):

```
solute       qqType   waterModel    chargeMethod    qmTheory    qmBasis    NumericalValues
Ammonia      fixed    SPCE          mbis            B3LYP       cc-pVTZ    1
Ammonia      OTFP     SPCE          mbis            B3LYP       cc-pVTZ    1
Ammonia      fixed    SPCE          mbis            MP2         cc-pVTZ    1
Ammonia      OTFP     SPCE          mbis            MP2         cc-pVTZ    1
Ammonia      fixed    SPCE          resp            B3LYP       cc-pVTZ    1
Ammonia      OTFP     SPCE          resp            B3LYP       cc-pVTZ    1
Ammonia      fixed    SPCE          resp            HF          6-31G*     1
Ammonia      OTFP     SPCE          resp            HF          6-31G*     1
Ammonia      fixed    SPCE          bcc             AM1         -          1
Ammonia      OTFP     SPCE          bcc             AM1         -          1
Ammonia      fixed    TIP3P         resp            HF          6-31G*     1
Ammonia      OTFP     TIP3P         resp            HF          6-31G*     1
Ammonia      fixed    TIP3P         resp            B3LYP       cc-pVTZ    1
Ammonia      OTFP     TIP3P         resp            B3LYP       cc-pVTZ    1
Ammonia      fixed    TIP3P         bcc             AM1         -          1
Ammonia      OTFP     TIP3P         bcc             AM1         -          1
                                                                           1
ACETAMIDE    fixed    SPCE          mbis            B3LYP       cc-pVTZ    1
ACETAMIDE    OTFP     SPCE          mbis            B3LYP       cc-pVTZ    1
ACETAMIDE    fixed    SPCE          mbis            MP2         cc-pVTZ    1
ACETAMIDE    OTFP     SPCE          mbis            MP2         cc-pVTZ    1
ACETAMIDE    fixed    SPCE          resp            B3LYP       cc-pVTZ    1
ACETAMIDE    OTFP     SPCE          resp            B3LYP       cc-pVTZ    1
ACETAMIDE    fixed    SPCE          resp            HF          6-31G*     1
ACETAMIDE    OTFP     SPCE          resp            HF          6-31G*     1
ACETAMIDE    fixed    SPCE          bcc             AM1         -          1
ACETAMIDE    OTFP     SPCE          bcc             AM1         -          1
ACETAMIDE    fixed    TIP3P         resp            HF          6-31G*     1
ACETAMIDE    OTFP     TIP3P         resp            HF          6-31G*     1
ACETAMIDE    fixed    TIP3P         resp            B3LYP       cc-pVTZ    1
ACETAMIDE    OTFP     TIP3P         resp            B3LYP       cc-pVTZ    1
ACETAMIDE    fixed    TIP3P         bcc             AM1         -          1
ACETAMIDE    OTFP     TIP3P         bcc             AM1         -          1
```

And here's my code so far:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('SI.xlsx')

def Extractor(dataframe,*match_criteria):

    for index,row in dataframe.iterrows():
        if len(set(row) & set(match_criteria)) == len(match_criteria):
            yield row

for occurence in Extractor(df,'OTFP','resp'):
    print(occurence)
```

Comment: you could use vectorized methods to check if an item is in a series. the column qqType can be checked with the pandas str contains method : df['qqType'].str.contains('OFTP'). if it is multiple strings, you can use isin and pass a list of strings: df['qqType'].isin(['OFTP', 'resp']). Using iterrows() is pretty slow.

Comment: Your question and approach does not make sense. Your data have different fields, e.g. `solute`, `qqType`, and generally, you don't want to mix `solute` with `qqType`. Why would you use `set` then?

Comment: The fields don't have many option (most only have two). This function makes sense for me in the context of a scientific paper I'm studying. I know what charge methods are and which will come up in the paper. If I want to quickly check the math behind one of the plots, this would be a convienient way of extracting relevant data from a large xlsx file in the supporting information of the publication. So I just go by rows and check for occurences of certain items.

Comment: If you're worried about performance, I would recommend staying far away from `.iterrows()`. _Now I want to do a series of boolean checks to see if certain elements (a matching string, a certain numerical value etc.) is in that `pd.Series`_ What would do then do based off of that check? You can probably use the vectorized methods provided by Pandas.